# Hostgator sub-domain not working

Tags: wordpress, magento, subdomain, multisite

**Introduction**

I'm new to hostgator and multisites, and my client has an account in hostgator, using the plan that you can have multisites.

The account already have a site "yyy.com" made by some other programmer that they don't work with anymore.

I need do develop a new site for them, hosted in that account, they dont have a domain for it yet, then i tried to create a subdomain on hostgator like xxx.yyy.com, but even waiting 8 hours i cant acess the subdomain, i want to install wordpress in it, to start developing the site.

**Techinical Information**

The yyy site is in: /home/username/public_html
The xxx subdomain is in /home/username/public_html/xxx.com

I used the "add subdomain" tool and softaculous app installer to install wordpress in that subdomain.

I think that the programmer of yyy.com used magento

**QUESTION**

What i'm doing wrong and how can i get it right?

(As a standard: sorry for english errors, its not my native language)

Comment: Did you try to move the document root of xxx.yyy.com to it's own root folder in the /home/username/ directory (eg. /home/username/xxx.yyy.com)?

Comment: I think  i found the problem, the site is hosted in another server and the domain is pointed at the other server, but the server that i was creating the subdomain only have the files of the site.

I don't know for sure, that site is gone to the prior programmer in another company now, so i don't have access anymore.

Comment: Ok, glad this is resolved!